# What is the most suitable design pattern for a frame-by-frame video processing application?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, video, computer-vision

I'm going to write a computer vision application that loads a video, do some image processing frame-by-frame, then display its result side by side with the original video. I also want to implement play, pause, and stop buttons and other gui stuffs.

All tutorials and articles that I've been through about computer vision is in procedural way, but I want to do it in OOP way.

What is the best design pattern for this problem?

For additional info, I think I'm going to use OpenCV (C++) and Qt for this project.

Comment: *"All tutorials and articles that I've been through about computer vision is in procedural way, but I want to do it in OOP way."* - Why? What are you trying to achieve with OO? Do you think there's a reason that everyone else uses procedural code for this task?

Comment: @MattDavey because they only cover how to use specific functions/operations to the image in our application, they don't cover how to wrap it all in a GUI application. I think I should use OOP because I want to have a better code maintainability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start from a similar but different example, it's a real-world one.

In practice, when you have, say, a native C++ library, you create a Java class accessing that library via native methods (each method being a Java wrapper for a C/C++ function call), and then use that class from Java. (Usually that wrapper class is a bit ugly from the conceptual point of view, that is, it contains strange auxiliary methods, native resource handles, etc.)

OO design is about assigning responsibilities; in the above case you assign responsibility of interaction with that native library to one class. Then, you let other classes use that class according to the application logic. Maybe, you create a wrapper (an Adapter providing a more sensible interface) for that library wrapper class.

Now about your case.

You most likely have some algorithms, that either are already coded or may be coded straightforwardly. *I would leave the algorithms as close to the book as possible.* (It's not a native library for Java, but a library of algorithms from a book.) Then, you create whatever classes that use this book-of-algorithms wrapper class.

As to the UI, you create a normal application UI. It would be wrong to create UI matching the internal structure of your data (or events that may happen with that data); you may use only the "data ready" event.

The reason is that changes in your UI must not affect your data and algotithms, and changes in your algorithms and data structures must not affect the UI.